# proper mapping between Stein manifolds

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

My question is the following:

Let $b:X \rightarrow Y$ be a proper holomorphic mapping between two Stein manifolds $X$ and $Y$. For obvious reasons, $b^{-1}(y)$ are finite subsets of $X$. Is the set 
$\lbrace \# b^{-1}(y)\, \colon\, y \in Y\rbrace $ bounded?

Here is the background: I'm trying to understand the equisingular stratification lemma in the paper "Eliashberg and Gromov: Embeeding of Stein manifold of dimension $n$ into the affine space of dimension $\frac{3}{2}n+1$, Annals of mathematics 1992".The anwser to the above question is yes according to their lemma.And if the anwser is yes,I can prove the existence of equisingular stratification.

A possible way to solve the question is: Denote by $A_i$ the subset of $Y$ consists of points $y \in Y$ with $\#b^{-1}(y) \geq i$, then they are analytic subsets of $Y$. If the number of irreducible components of $A_i$ are finite,then the anwser is yes. The problem is that $Y$ is not a compact manifold and $A_i$ may have infinite many components.

Comment: You must be assuming $Y$ is connected.  Are you assuming $X$ is connected or $b$ is surjective?  It is false without at least one of those, so please state all of your hypotheses.

Comment: If $X$ is connected and $b$ is surjective then $X$ and $Y$ have the same dimension at all points, so $b$ is necessarily flat (in the sense of maps of local rings), so the coherent sheaf $b_{\ast}(O_X)$ is a vector bundle on $Y$.  The rank of this vector bundle must be constant since $Y$ is connected, and it provides a uniform upper bound on the size of fibers. Are you interested in cases with either $X$ disconnected or $b$ not surjective?

Comment: I'm sorry for the ambiguous.The map $b$ is in general not surjective.$X$ and $Y$ are both smooth and connected.Thank you for the comments.